# Body of http request is received as "raw data"

Tags: flutter, http, rust

Building a web app with flutter + rust, I'm having issues with post requests to create new users.

On the flutter side, I'm creating a http request with the user's data in the body like so :

```dart
Future<http.Response> createUserRequest(String email, String name, String forename, String password) {
  // start by hashing the pass
  var hashPass = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(password));
  // post the request
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://$waterFlowServerAddress/main/auth/create_user'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: json.encode(<String, String>{
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'forename': forename,
      'pwhash': hashPass.toString(),
    }),
  );
}
```

Then on the server, I'm receiving it with [afire](https://docs.rs/afire/latest/afire/) and trying to get the data of the body in a route :

```rust
server.route(Method::POST, "/main/auth/create_user/", |req| {
    println!("{:?}", req);
});
```

Except it shows me this :

```
Request { 
method: POST, 
path: "/main/auth/create_user", 
version: "HTTP/1.1", 
path_params: [], query: 
Query { data: [] }, 
headers: [Header { name: "user-agent", value: "Dart/2.18 (dart:io)" }, Header { name: "content-type", value: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }, Header { name: "accept-encoding", value: "gzip" }, Header { name: "content-length", value: "112" }, Header { name: "host", value: "127.0.0.1:8080" }], 
cookies: [], 
body: [], 
address: "127.0.0.1:52544", 
raw_data: [80, 79, 83, 84, 32, 47, 109, 97, 105, 110, 47, 97, 117, 116, 104, 47, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 95, 117, 115, 101, 114, 32, 72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 13, 10, 117, 115, 101, 114, 45, 97, 103, 101, 110, 116, 58, 32, 68, 97, 114, 116, 47, 50, 46, 49, 56, 32, 40, 100, 97, 114, 116, 58, 105, 111, 41, 13, 10, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 116, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110, 59, 32, 99, 104, 97, 114, 115, 101, 116, 61, 85, 84, 70, 45, 56, 13, 10, 97, 99, 99, 101, 112, 116, 45, 101, 110, 99, 111, 100, 105, 110, 103, 58, 32, 103, 122, 105, 112, 13, 10, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 49, 49, 50, 13, 10, 104, 111, 115, 116, 58, 32, 49, 50, 55, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 58, 56, 48, 56, 48, 13, 10, 13, 10]
}
```

I don't know why the data is in the `raw_data` field and not the body ? Am I missing something ?

#### Edit :

After parsing the `raw_data` back to a string, I get :

```
POST /main/auth/create_user HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Dart/2.18 (dart:io)
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 112
host: 127.0.0.1:8080
```

So clearly, I'm not getting the body at all. However, looking at the http request with wireshark, the body is in it. So it seems to be a server side issue ?

#### Edit 2 :

I managed to get a body with a simple python request :

```py
import requests
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/main/auth/create_user', json={"key": "value"})
```

Here is the result I got on the server when displaying the request :

```
POST /main/auth/create_user HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

{"key": "value"}
```

Is there any difference in the headers that would explain why one request's body is getting skip ?

#### Edit 3 :

I've cloned the afire lib to start debuging it myself, and turns out I'm getting only the header all the way from the `TcpStream`. The library does not do any check on wether the message is complete, and I'm guessing that is the issue.

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but the `application/json` media type [does not have a `charset` parameter](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json).

Comment: This is a tough one. Can you please specify which version of afire you are using? I start to suspect this is a bug in the `Request` class.

Comment: @DaSourcerer I'm using afire 1.2.0, last version on crates.io.

Comment: Got to admit defeat here. According to the [`Request` implementation](https://github.com/Basicprogrammer10/afire/blob/v1.2.0/lib/request.rs#L45), everything should be fine. I'd suggest filing an issue with afire.

Comment: @DaSourcerer With further digging, a simple python command works :
`import requests`
`r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/main/auth/create_user', json={"key": "value"})`
The server will have an actual body.

Comment: @DaSourcerer I modified a bit the afire lib, it works now ! 
I'm fairly new to how to help these kind of projects, how can I submit my changes for review ?